# Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3.0 and Blazor Web Assembly App Template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor

I have Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3.0. I do not see the Web Assembly template in Visual Studio when I do a new project. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Blazor WebAssembly is not included in stable `.Net Core 3.0`.

[See here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-release-candidate-1/):

> *.NET Core 3.0 RC1 requires Visual Studio 2019 16.3 Preview 4 or later.*
>
> There is also a Blazor WebAssembly preview update available with this release. This update to Blazor WebAssembly still has a Preview 9 version, but carries an updated build number. This is not a release candidate for Blazor WebAssembly. Blazor WebAssembly isn’t expected to ship as a stable release until some time after .NET Core 3.0 ships (details coming soon!).

So you have to be patient or use a Preview-Version:

> To install the latest Blazor WebAssembly template run the following command:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview9.19457
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use CLI to create the project using dotnet new blazorwasm

Comment: After final release of .NET Core SDK 3.0 , still we have to install preview 9 ??  , I am asking because after updating VS and SDK to latest version , not a single blazor project is working

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet new blazorwasm

dotnet new blazorserver --auth Individual

dotnet new --help
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing in your answer.